# How to find in lines \n\t and replace them with \t? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, replace, line

In a csv-file ([tab] stands for a tabulation) :

```
R456  
R457  
[tab]trutz  
R457  
[tab]trutz  
R458  
Z32  
[tab]frot
```

My wished output :

```
R456  
R457[tab]trutz  
R457[tab]trutz  
R458  
Z32[tab]frot
```

So, it is about replacing `\n\t` with `\t`. But a `line.replace('\n\t','\t')` does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any packages like `pandas`? How does `line.replace('\n\t','\t')` not work?

Answer (score 0):

Use `str. rstrip()` to remove a trailing newline.
This will remove the newline but will keep the tab.